# prime number generation code in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, primes

I'm trying the following approach for generating primes:

```
primes = [2]
candidate = 3
MILLION = 1000000
while candidate < MILLION:
    if all(candidate % prime for prime in primes if prime**2 <= candidate):
        primes.append(candidate)
    candidate += 2
```

However, this is comparatively much slower than my previous code, where I wasn't using the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function, and was making the checks myself as below:

```
primes = [2]
candidate = 3
MILLION = 1000000
while candidate < MILLION:
    can_be_prime = True
    for p in primes:
        if p**2 > candidate:
            break
        elif candidate % p == 0:
            can_be_prime = False
            break
    if can_be_prime:
        primes.append(candidate)
    candidate += 2
```

While the second one gets over within 10 seconds, the first one takes forever to complete. Can someone help me understand why the first one starts outputting so slowly after the first 100000 numbers?

Comment: if you want an efficient way, use a sieve  of eratosthenes, mine took  283 ms to run. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Actually, I'm solving some problems on project Euler and many a times, I generate the primes on the fly, and so I follow the approach above. I will try using the sieve next time onwards when I know in advance the range in which prime numbers are needed, or if I want them pre-stored.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Actually, `candidate % prime` is `True`, if the modulo is non-zero. So the condition effectively becomes `if (candidate % prime) is non-zero for all primes`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You would want to do `candidate % prime != 0` though, as you need to invert the condition (you want to add the candidate as a prime, when you can’t find a previous prime that divides it).

Comment: @poke, yep I realised that after I wrote it!

Comment: @mu無, a sieve will behave exactly as your code is doing.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham In this case, yes it will because I have a limit, but not when I don't have the limit. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) `Sieve of Eratosthenes is a simple, ancient algorithm for finding all prime numbers up to any given limit.`

Comment: use `takewhile()` from itertools to cut short the enumeration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While your idea to shorten the code using that generator expression and `any` is good, they are not equivalent. In particular, in your longer solution, you are iterating the (sorted) list of primes and *break* the iteration as soon as you found a prime for which `p ** 2 > candidate` is true.

In your generator expression however, you try to make this check using `x for p in primes if p ** 2 <= candidate`. This is unfortunately *not* the same. Even if that check fails, the generator will still continue to iterate over the remaining primes, performing that `p ** 2` for *every single* prime, on *every iteration* of the outer `while` loop.

You can verify that this is the problem, if you write it a bit differently:

```
def getPrimes (candidate):
    for p in primes:
        if p ** 2 > candidate:
            break
        yield p

while candidate < MILLION:
    if all(candidate % prime for prime in getPrimes(candidate)):
        primes.append(candidate)
    candidate += 2
```

So now, we’re using the same idea from the longer version and abort the iteration on `primes` as soon as we hit a prime for which `p ** 2 > candidate` is true. That way, we get the speed from the longer solution back.

Comment: I was thinking on similar lines, and then I read this https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all , which says it returns a False at the first occurrence

Comment: @mu無 `all` is short-circuiting, yes, but for correct prime numbers—which only result in trueish values—it will still have to iterate the whole generator. And the generator itself does not break early on the ordered list of primes when it hits the mentioned threshold.

Answer (score 0):

we can actually use `6n +/- 1` rule for generating primes.
for example if you want to generate primes for a given number:

```
def primes(N):
    if N == 2:
        primes = [2]
    elif N >= 3:
        primes = [2, 3]
    else:
        return None
    for i in range(6, N):
        if i % 6 == 0:
            left = i - 1
            right = i + 1
            if all(left % p != 0 for p in primes):
                primes.append(left)
            if all(right % p != 0 for p in primes):
                primes.append(right)
    return primes
```